# ingress nginx 404 not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Created a kubernetes cluster, and installed ingress-nginx controller. I am getting a 404 not found if i go to the ingress-nginx-controller load balancer external ip that is aa************.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
kubectl create namespace ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

to get the service:

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                             PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.100.219.162   aa************.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:32091/TCP,443:32305/TCP   154m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.100.208.135   <none>                                                                  443/TCP                      154m

my ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: factory
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: factory.**.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: factory
            port: 
              number: 80
  - host: api.factory.**.com # myfactoryapi-factorydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: factory
            port: 
              number: 8082
```

all my namespace

```
 kubectl get namespace
NAME               STATUS   AGE
default            Active   34d
ingress-nginx      Active   160m
kerberos-factory   Active   34d
kube-node-lease    Active   34d
kube-public        Active   34d
kube-system        Active   34d
mongodb            Active   8d
```

to get my ingress

```
 kubectl get ing -n kerberos-factory                                                                               
NAME      CLASS    HOSTS                                             ADDRESS                                                                 PORTS   AGE
factory   <none>   factory.**.com,api.factory.**.com   a****.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80      65m
```

to describe the ingress

```
 kubectl describe ing -n kerberos-factory                                                                          
Name:             factory
Namespace:        kerberos-factory
Address:          a********.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                       Path  Backends
  ----                       ----  --------
  factory.***.com      
                             /   factory:80 (192.168.34.220:80)
  api.factory.***.com  
                             /   factory:8082 (192.168.34.220:8082)
Annotations:                 kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                  ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    3m8s (x3 over 4m51s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

why am i getting 404 not found

Comment: Nginx will only route to your pod if the `Host` header in the request matches one of the hosts it has an ingress for. If you are accessing via load balancer DNS name, host header will not match what you have configured.